# Alter Links/Menu to show a modal dialog

Tags: 8, ajax, navigation

I have two type of roles 'base' and 'full'. For the base role I would like to alter some menu links to open a modal dialog instead of the original destination url. I would like to replace the link. I know about route subscriber and how to change the route. But in my case I want to change the link (use an ajax enabled link and open a modal dialog instead). Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use hook_link_alter

```
function hook_link_alter(&$variables) {
  $url = $variables['url'];

  if ($url->isRouted() && $url->getRouteName() == 'user.login') {
    $variables['options']['attributes']['data-dialog-type'] = 'modal';
    $variables['options']['attributes']['class'] = 'use-ajax';
  }
}
```

See more details here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_link_alter/8.5.x

Comment: thanks, this is what I was searching for. Is there any possibility to attach a library to the link or do I need to use hook_page_attachments to attach it?

Comment: @Matthias np, yes you have to use hook_page_attachments or extend global library in your theme (it depends on accessibility of your assets: js/css).